# Cannot resolve symbol 'OnSuccessListener' in Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services, google-cloud-firestore, cannot-find-symbol

I'm getting this strange behavior that I'm not able to import `OnSuccessListener` to my code after git cloning and building in a different machine (this resolved fine in my previous machine). However the project builds fine and runs on the emulator. But I'm not able to write firebase related codes further as the listener isn't resolving.

[image]

I tried cleaning the project, rebuilding, invalidating the cache but still no luck.

Gradle Dependencies,

```
dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.34.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.github.drawers:SpinnerDatePicker:1.0.6'
    implementation 'com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.2'
}
```

Comment: Have you tried removing `.idea/libraries` ?

Comment: I tried removing build folder and rebuild the project. Still project builds fine with above not resolving error in the given class.

Comment: Tried deleting .idea/* still no luck

Comment: I think the method for OnSuccessListner may be of a different class. Block the code for this method. And write it again, it will ask for from which class you want to create the method. Then select the correct one.

Comment: Have you tried to manually import `OnSuccessListener` using this line `import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;`? Please responde with @.

Answer (score 2):

Please try adding this into your app-gradle file.

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:16.0.1'

Answer (score -1):

What you do is make all the firebase and gms version of the same number like for example:

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:102.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.0'

Comment: This is no longer a requirement, latest libraries can have different versions without clashing

Comment: Yes this is not a requirement for firebase sdk. In fact google suggests you to use the latest firebase library. Also sometimes there are no matching version numbers with respective firebase services.